# Касаемо орбит планет(,) не изменилось бы ровным счëтом ничего

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводный-оборот

Нужна запятая?

> Что будет, если черная дыра той же массы заменит Солнце? Касаемо орбит планет(,) не изменилось бы ровным счëтом ничего, то есть орбиты остаются неизменными.

Похоже на какой-то вводный оборот, не находите? Ни туда ни оттуда вопрос не так-то просто задать.

Оформляю цитированием, т. к. фраза не моя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая ставится:

***Касаемо орбит планЕт**, не изменилось бы ровным счëтом ничегО, то есть орбиты остаются неизменными.*

**КАСАЕМО**, предлог. кого-чего. Нар.-разг. = Касательно. Кое-что касаемо прошлого я помню.

Обособление в общем случае  **факультативное**. Здесь оборот **распространенный**, он логически подчеркнут.

Сравнить: ***Что касается орбит планЕт,** не изменилось бы ничегО...*

Comment: Интересно, а зачем вы сделали буквы заглавными?

Comment: На эти слова падает ударение (повышение тона на ударном слоге), вследствие чего пауза//остановка голоса четко слышится. Эта пауза обозначается запятой. При отсутствии подчеркнутого ударения пауза небольшая (произносительная),  поэтому запятой нет. Другими словами, постановку знаков можно считывать с произношения.  Вы хотите логически подчеркнуть оборот (семантика) и  тогда выделяете его голосом (интонация).

Comment: Спасибо! Я думал, здесь не зависит от постановки паузы. Ваш вариант принимается.